# Clear all running intervals

Tags: javascript, node.js, setinterval, clearinterval

I am trying to clear all intervals at the same time with the same ID.

Reason for this is so multiple agents can have calls originated to them, so it works accordingly but when more than one agent/interval is involved the interval is not cleared and to the best of my understanding clearInterval only ever clears the last interval.

Is it possible to clear all Intervals all the same time with the same ID? or just clear all intervals?

I looked at the other questions regarding the same topic but didn't work for me and wondered if there was an up to date method of handling this.

**Basic Code Idea:**

```
var extenArray = [];

//Passport.js
app.get('/index', checkLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
      isAuthenticated : req.isAuthenticated(),
      user : req.user
    });
    if(extenArray.length > 0){ 
      intervalId = setInterval(bridgeCall, 10000);
      console.log("Running");
    }
  });

  function bridgeCall() {
    if (extenArray.length > 0) {
       console.log("Begin!")
       console.log("value removed from array");
    } else {
      error = ("No extensions left to dial");
      Error();
      if(extenArray.length < 1){
      clearInterval(intervalId);
      console.log("Cleared Interval")
      }
    }
  }
```

Every time a extension is called its removed from the array but I want to keep the code sample as possible, but can flesh it out if required.

Is there a way to clear all the intervals with the same ID at the same time?

Comment: each interval has a unique ID

Comment: @JaromandaX ok, so is it possible to stop all intervals currently running?

Comment: by keeping track of all intervalID's, say in an array, you can

Comment: you can run a for loop from 0 -> 1000 to clear all intervalID :)

Comment: *"to the best of my understanding clearInterval only ever clears the last interval."* - No, it clears only the interval with the specified id, and if no interval matches it does nothing.

Comment: @kpsingh unreliable. A browser could allocate from different sequences based on the interval length, the handler source code hash, current phase of the Moon or a number of plenty other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @JaromandaX for the suggestion I configured my code and it works based of the suggestion to keep all of all interval ID's in an array.

Made modifications to the code sample given:

```
var extenArray = [];
var interVal = [];

//Passport.js
app.get('/index', checkLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        isAuthenticated : req.isAuthenticated(),
        user : req.user
    });
    if (extenArray.length > 0) {
        intervalId = setInterval(bridgeCall, 10000);
        interValArray.push(intervalId);
        console.log("Running");
    }
});

function bridgeCall() {
    if (extenArray.length > 0) {
        console.log("Begin!")
        console.log("value removed from array");
    } else {
        error = ("No extensions left to dial");
        Error();
        if (extenArray.length < 1) {
            for (i = 0; i < interValArray.length; i++) {
                clearInterval(interValArray[i]);
                console.log("Cleared Interval")
            }
        }
    }
}
```